# How to fix the error Cannot destructure property temperatureData of 'undefined' or 'null' in react without class

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

CODE:

```
const { temperatureData } = state;

return (
    <>
        <div className="flex flex-row">
        {temperatureData.map((item, i) => (
            <div className="flex flex-auto rounded justify-center items-center text-center p-2 m-1 bg-white" key={i}>
                <div className="text-md font-bold flex flex-col">
                    {format(new Date(item.date * 1000), 'EEEE')}
                </div>
                <div className="text-md flex flex-col">
                    {format(new Date(item.date * 1000), 'MMM dd')}
                </div>
                <div className="w-full h-20">
                    <img className="h-20" src={`/images/icons/weather/${getIcon(item.img)}.svg`} key={i} />
                </div>
                <div className="text-gray-700">{item.temp}</div>
            </div>
        ))}
        </div>
    </>
);
```

How to fix the error Cannot destructure property `temperatureData` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
The problem is when I reload the app the error will just appear.
do I need to put a condition inside the return?
if (state) {....HTML CODE}

Comment: for the looks of your component, I assume you're using a React Function component, thus not defining a `state` variable inside the visible scope. What's happening is that `state` is resolving to `undefined` at runtime, causing your destructuring attempt to throw an exception. Consider using React hook `useState` to initialize `temperatureData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, your state variable itself is not initialized when the app bootstraps.  I presume you're using a functional component since you said in the title "Without class", so to initialize state you'd need your useState declaration to look something like this:

```
    const [state, setState] = useState({ temperatureData: [] })
```

Note the param of the useState function is the initial state, so if you just called `useState()` with no arguments the inital value would be undefined.

Although with functional components, multiple independent state variables are more common, so perhaps a better pattern might be this:

```
    const [temperatures, setTemperatures] = useState([])

    return <>{temperatures.map(t => <> ... </>)}</>
```